# Run coded UI in windows form VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have been having a problem getting my coded UI to work at a button click. I seem to 
continually be getting errors like

> "'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common.UITestLogWrapper'
>   threw an exception."

I was wondering if there was a reference I was missing or I need to change my initialization code?

Here is my code so far 
'

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.Initialize();
            CodedUITestProject.CodedUITest1 coded = new CodedUITestProject.CodedUITest1();
            coded.Method();
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.Cleanup();
        }
    }
}'
```

Noting that
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.extension.Uia
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.extension.ie
are not located in the private or public assembly folders (is that a 2012 thing?)

Both of the projects are in .NET Framework 4

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I hear for you bro same thing here as well :(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem you list above by adding a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Logging out of the PrivateAssemblies directory.  However, I am getting errors loading the IE Interop assembly even though I have it referenced.  Hope that helps you get farther than I have.

Answer (score 0):

The assemblies  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.extension.Uia  and Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.extension.ie that you need would be found in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSTT\12.0" although I am not sure if it solves your problem.

Answer (score -1):

add reference from..\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies.
i means just add reference from PrivateAssemblies and PublicAssemblies is enough.
remember to check Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.IE.Communication.Interop.dll this is referenced in your debug folder